# He makes everything [to] look good

Tags: grammar, infinitives

> - He makes everything look good
> - He makes everything to look good

I am wondering if someone tries to *make everything look good* or *to look good*. 
Please help me understand

Comment: Related:  [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083)

Answer (score 2):

There's this archaic usage in the [KJV Bible...](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-23-2/)

> *He maketh me **to** lie down in green pastures*

...but [all modern versions](http://biblehub.com/psalms/23-2.htm) will render this as...

> *He **makes me lie down** in green pastures*

Note that ***lie down*** and OP's ***look*** are [*unmarked infinitives*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/need-to-understand-infinitive). Most verbs that can precede an infinitive in such constructions require the *full infinitive* (i.e. - including ***to***). But some, particularly verbs of [perception, permission, or causation](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/styleguide/chapter/infinitives/), require the unmarked form...

> *He made me go*
>    *He watched me leave*
>    *I saw her arrive*
>    *I heard her sing*
>    *They let us watch*

---

The main point to note is that the *default* is to include the infinitive marker ***to***. But with ***make*** that default now sounds quaint/archaic, whereas with ***help*** it's become completely optional (in many contexts, *It helps me sleep* and *It helps me **to** sleep* are equivalent and interchangeable).

Probably you just have to learn which verbs work like this, but if anyone can add information in comments I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: *Make* takes a bare infinitival complement, but it takes a *to*-infinitival complement when cast in the passive: *My parents made me **wash** the dishes*, but *I was made **to wash** the dishes*.  No other verb works like this, so yes, you have to memorize it.

Comment: There's a decent explanation [**here**](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/styleguide/chapter/infinitives/) under the heading **The Bare Infinitive:** _Verbs of perception, permission, or causation, such as see, watch, hear, make, let, and have (after a direct object)_ (in addition to _do_ and _will, would, can,_ etc.)

Comment: @snailpane ...and then there's **let,** which has _no_ passive form...

Comment: @P. E. Dant: ty for link. I've amended the answer a bit, but all that stuff about bare infinitives and auxiliary verbs seems a bit too much to throw in here.

Answer (score 1):

"He makes everything look good," usually means that he improves the quality of whatever he is associated with. For example, you could say "He makes golf pants look good," that is, something that normally doesn't look good (golf pants), by contrast, looks good when he's wearing them. This is probably the most common phrasing, and if you're generally trying to promote a positive reaction, this is the one you want to use.

Edit: Likewise, this is used if, in fact, everything he makes looks good.

Comment: +1 - It's worthwhile to explore this a little, because the OP may have encountered exactly this colloquial usage. cf. "I make this look good!" as in [**this link.**](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/8e4f1176-0a8a-418c-ac84-ee10e6ad2605)